# Filtering for specific Domains using Get-ADForest or ([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to filter domains that contain a specific string ("sa*") utilizing either get-adforest or .net commands.  In the end the list of domains will be used to populate a combobox in a form.

```
$DomainList = ($Forest.Domains).name | sort -CaseSensitive
foreach ($Domain in $Domainlist){if ($Domain -like "sa*"){$Domains = $Domain}}

or

get-adforest | where-object {$_.Domains -like "sa*"}
```

Expecting the result to only include domains that begin with sa.

sam.domain.com

sandy.domain.com

etc...

Instead get multiple errors or no results at all.

Comment: This should work: `Get-ADForest | Where-Object {$_.Domains -like "*.com"}` as an example. If it does not work and you receiving an error, please update the OP. If you are getting no results, just run `Get-ADForest` and make sure `Domains` is populated with what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with both attempts.

In your first attempt you were using `($Forest.Domains).name`, which was trying to read a `name` property from the list of domains, which doesn't exist. Instead, you want the list of domains itself:

```
$DomainList = (Get-ADForest).Domains | sort -CaseSensitive
foreach ($Domain in $Domainlist) { if ($Domain -like "sa*") { $Domains = $Domain } }
```

In your second attempt, you were piping the results from `Get-ADForest` into the `Where-Object`, so the results included any *forest* that matched the criteria, rather than any domain that did. So to get a filtered list of domains, you need to pipe the list of domains into the `Where-Object`.

```
(Get-ADForest).Domains | Where-Object {$_ -like "sa*"}
```

Note that `(Get-ADForest).Domains` will only give you a list of strings containing the DNS name of the domains. You did mention using [`GetCurrentForest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getcurrentforest) instead. The benefit there is you can get more info about each domain (like a list of domain controllers).

If that matters to you, you can get a list of [`Domain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain) objects that match the criteria like this:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Domains |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "sa*"}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel Luci.  the (Get-ADForest).Domains | Where-Object {$_ -like "sa*"} is providing exactly what I'm looking for.

The First one is only populating one domain and the second one provides a little more than what I need at this point.  Right now, I was just looking for the list of domains so that I may populate a combo box on a form load.